# How do i use Windows task manager to run a command?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task to run on through the windows task manager to run this command

```
C:\php\php.exe -f "C:\leads\my_file.php"
```

I can run the file by going to cmd and typing the command but in the windows task manager there is a place for actions but i have no idea how to put my command there to run that instead....any ideas

Comment: on [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html) and [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Comment: it has a place for a program /script and a place for an argument (optional)

Comment: yes same as windows 7 but there is no place to enter the command

Comment: Yes, program script: `C:\php\php.exe` and Add arguments: `-f "C:\leads\my_file.php"`

Answer (score 1):

i'd put it in a vbs and run it from there.

you can reference the vbs w/

cscript "c:\path\nameofvbs.vbs"

that will run the script or in schedule task just put the .vbs file name and it should run.

the content of the .vbs would be

```
    Set oShell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell") 
        oShell.Run "C:\php\php.exe -f C:\leads\my_file.php", 0, False 
    WScript.Quit
```

Comment: so all i do is put all the code you pasted in a file named something.vbs and then select it from the schedule task